# Вставка значений из выбранного массива в поля таблицы

Tags: php, postgresql

Есть HTML таблица:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="street">Street:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="building_no">Building No:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number of building (XXXX)" name="bld_no">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="ID Sector">ID Sector:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="IotaNet Sector (5)" name="id_sector">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="ID Block">ID Block:</label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" placeholder="IotaNet Block (XXX)" name="id_block">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="Levels">Levels:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number of floors" name="levels">
  </td>
</tr>
```

в этом же файле есть PHP код с запросом к БД, который правильно выводит указанные в запросе значения из БД

```js
$qexist = "SELECT
test.tb_54646.street,
  test.tb_54646.bld_no,
  test.tb_54646.id_sector,
  test.tb_54646.id_block,
  test.tb_54646.levels
FROM
test.tb_54646
WHERE test.tb_54646.street = '$street'
AND test.tb_54646.bld_no = '$bld_no'
";

$ress = pg_query($qexist);

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ress)) {

  echo $row[0].
  'street';
  echo $row[1].
  'bld_no';
  echo $row[2].
  'id_sector';
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
}
```

подскажите пожалуйста, каким кодом передать эти значения в поля формы с конкретным атрибутами id или name?

echo просто пишет значения из массива внизу таблицы

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71682/discussion-on-question-by-boris-grebnevskyi-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось в создании нового массива и присвоения каждому элементу нового массива значений элементов старого. Честно сказать не понимаю почему это так работает, нашёл просто экспериментальным путём, пробуя различные варианты, если кто-то объяснит, почему работает именно так, буду благодарен.

```js
<?php>
$qexist = "SELECT 
       test.tb.id_bld, 
       test.tb.street, 
       test.tb.bld_no, 
  FROM test.tb
  WHERE test.tb.street = '$street'
  AND test.tb.bld_no = '$bld_no'
  "; 
  $ress = pg_query($qexist);
  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ress)) { 
        $value[0] = $row[0];
        $value[1] = $row[1];
        $value[2] = $row[2];
  }
 ?>
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <form method="get" action="t54646.php">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="id_bld">Building ID:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Not for fill - system ordered" name="id_bld" value="<?php echo $value[0] ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="street">Street:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)" value="<?php echo $value[1] ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="building_no">Building No:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Number of building (XXXX)" name="bld_no" value="<?php echo $value[2] ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>
```